Bad spacing after multicols environment
I get sometimes a bad spacing at the bottom of a multicols inserted into a boxed environment (like minipage, tcolorbox or mdframed).
For example, with a minipage (and a tight \framebox for visualization):
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\noindent\framebox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
  \begin{multicols}{2}
      \lipsum[1-2]

      This is an equation:
      \[ \frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1-x} = \sum_{i=1}^n x^i \]
  \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}}


The portions of letters below the baseline and the \sum subscript are outside the box.
This looks similar to the question Inconsistent spacing after multicols inside figure, but the patch given in the answer doesn't work here (furthermore, it was a bug fixed in 2020 LaTeX release).
Here a complete example with a minipage and a tcolorbox (my original question):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\noindent\framebox{%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
  \begin{multicols}{2}
      \lipsum[1-2]

      This is an equation:
      \[ \frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1-x} = \sum_{i=1}^n x^i \]
  \end{multicols}
\end{minipage}}

\bigskip

\begin{tcolorbox}[size=minimal, colback=yellow]
  \begin{multicols}{2}
      \lipsum[1-2]

      This is an equation:
      \[ \frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1-x} = \sum_{i=1}^n x^i \]
  \end{multicols}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}



Have you tried using the side-by-side feature of tcolorbox instead of multicols? I doubt you've meant to combine the two this way. The tcolorbox docs demonstrate using boxes inside multicols, but I'm not sure it is meant to work the other way around as tcolorbox has its own methods for columns within boxes. Plus, even where supported, there are caveats and manual intervention is required.

@cfr As I know, with side by side tcolorbox, the column break must be set manually, with \tcblower. I look for a two columns text, with columns of the same length built automatically, like provided by the package multicol.

As I said, according to the manual, you have to do some intervention by hand even in the case where there's an expectation of your combining the two. So I somewhat doubt this is the kind of think you're likely to get a solution for here unless it happens to strike somebody as a sufficiently interesting problem. Perhaps a feature request to tcolorbox's maintainer(s) for auto-breaking inside boxes?
